# FFmpeg video from file to network

Tags: c, c++11, ffmpeg

I am currently working with FFmpeg in a video streaming solution over RTP. What bugs me is how to stream at a correct framerate. Currently I am using a sleep in the main streaming loop:

```
while (av_read_frame (input_format_ctx, &packet) >= 0) { // Read a video packet as long as EOF is not reached or an error occurr
        if(packet.stream_index == 0) {
            if (av_interleaved_write_frame(output_format_ctx, &packet) < 0) { // Write the packet to the output stream
                av_packet_unref(&packet); // Wipe the packet
                av_free_packet(&packet); // Release the packet and finishes if a problem occured
                break; 
            }
            av_packet_unref(&packet); // Wipe the packet
            av_free_packet(&packet); // Release the packet
        }

        current_time = getSystemTime(); // Get system time
        adaptativeSleep ((last_time + 1/(output_framerate)) - current_time); // Sleep according to framerate
        last_time = getSystemTime(); // Get finish 
    }
```

Is there a correct way of letting FFmpeg handle the framerate?

Thanks in advance

P.S.: I only remux the stream, as a result FFmpeg runs through the file in a few seconds witought my "sleep".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AVCodecContext.pkt_timebase` and `AVCodecContext.time_base` is what you will need to keep the stream running smoothly. Each stream has its own `pkt_timebase`. When broadcasting, use one stream to sync to the system clock. Use the `AVPacket.pts` and FFMpegs function `av_q2d()` to convert the pts value to seconds as a double value.

```
double time_base = av_q2d(ctx->pkt_timebase);
int64_t time_stamp = packet->pts;
double packet_time = time_base * time_stamp; // time stamp in seconds
```

From there sync the first streams packet to the system clock. The pauses between sending the following packets will be easier to handle.

The following function is nothing to do with streaming but does illustrate syncing with a system clock.

```
FFVideoFrame *FFMpeg::getVideoFrame(double r_time) { // r_time is current system time
    FFVideoFrame *vframe = nullptr;

    double timestamp;
    double clock_current_time = r_time - sys_clock_start;
    double clock_current_frame = 0.0;

    mutex_vid_queues.lock();

    int vid_queue_size = vid_queue.size();

    if (playback_started) {
        if (vid_queue_size > MAX_VID_OVERRUN) { // keep the buffer queues low
            playback_clock_start += 0.75;
            LOGD("TIMESHIFT buffers over MAX_VID_OVERRUN");
        } else if (vid_queue_size < 20) {
            playback_clock_start -= 0.4; // resync
            LOGD("TIMESHIFT buffers below 20");
        }
    }

    if (!playback_started) {
        // queued video buffers need to be at least 1 second for network stream

        if (((vid_queue_size > MIN_VID_FRAMES_START_NON_NETWORK && !isNetworkStream)
                || (vid_queue_size > MIN_VID_FRAMES_START && isNetworkStream))
                ) {

            playback_started = true;

            vframe = vid_queue.front();
            vid_queue.pop_front();

            playback_clock_start = vframe->timestamp_f; // set stream start time from time stamp

            sys_clock_start = r_time; // set system start time from current time
        }
    } else {
        bool in_bounds = true;
        FFVideoFrame *frame_temp;
        int drop_count = 0;

        while (in_bounds) {
            if (vid_queue_size == 0) {
                in_bounds = false;
            } else {
                frame_temp = vid_queue.front();

                timestamp = frame_temp->timestamp_f;
                clock_current_frame = timestamp - playback_clock_start;

                if (clock_current_frame > clock_current_time) {
                    in_bounds = false;
                } else {

                    // adds 0.xx of a second tolerance for video playback REMOVED FROM HERE
                    // this may get increased at some point

                    vid_queue.pop_front();
                    vid_queue_size--;

                    if (isNetworkStream
                        && fabs(clock_current_time - clock_current_frame) < 0.05) {
                        in_bounds = false;
                    }

                    if (vframe) {
                        vid_unused.push_back(vframe);
                        drop_count++;
                    }

                    vframe = frame_temp;
                }
            }
        }

        // if rendering takes too long then dropped frames will occur

        if (drop_count > 0) LOGD("Dumped %d video frames", drop_count);
    }

    mutex_vid_queues.unlock();

    if (vframe) clock_last_frame = (int64_t)timestamp;

    return vframe;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I will reimplement with this strategy. I saw in the tutorials  that I could pass information to the stream and context(AVRational). Do you think I can make libav do the job for me? Or sleeping manually is the only option?

Comment: And if you have an example of this strategy and could share it, I will appreciate a lot!

Comment: The 'ffmpeg' command handles that for you with a specific switch but the API you have to handle the pauses yourself. Just hold back the packets until the their time is below the system clock. I use a similar method when syncing audio, video and subtitle streams on playback. Have so many packets in the buffer and only read them in as they are being released.

Comment: I have implemented and works perfectly. Thank you very very much!